# Error stack trace en MVC

Tags: php

Utilizo modelo vista controlador (MVC) y tengo este error en la hoja de rutas(routes.php):

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ArticuloController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\routes.php:37 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\index.php(27): call('ticket', 'index') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\routes.php on line 37**

codigo:

```html
<?php

 //función que llama al controlador y su respectiva acción, que son pasados como parámetros
 function call($controller, $action){
  //importa el controlador desde la carpeta Controllers
  require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');

  //crea el controlador
  switch($controller){
   case 'cliente':
    require_once('Models/claseCliente.php');
    $controller= new ClienteController();
                        switch($action){
        
                                        case 'index':
                                        $controller->index();
                                        break;
                                        case 'registrar':
                                        $controller->register();
        
        
                                    }
                                       break;
            case 'ticket':
                require_once('Models/claseTicket.php');
                $controllerTicket=new TicketController();
                    switch($action){
                        
                            case 'index':
                                $controllerTicket->index();
                                break;
                            case 'buscar':
                                $controllerTicket->buscar();
                    }
            case 'articulo':
            require_once('Models/claseProducto.php');
                $controllerArt= new ArticuloController();
                switch($action){
                        
                            case 'index':
                                $controllerArt->index();
                                break;
                            case 'buscar':
                                $controllerArt->buscar();
                    }
   }
           
 
 
    }
?>
```

El error se da al entrar al index de ticket, aparentemente llama al index de articulo aunque no deberia, si entro al index de articulo va perfecto.

Pero no se bien que es un stack trace.

Gracias

Comment: Puedes poner algo de codigo donde haces la llamad de la clase ticket, y ademas yo que tu cerraria cada uno de los case de cada switch

Answer (score 1):

Me faltaba un break, acabo de darme cuenta:

```html
<?php

 //función que llama al controlador y su respectiva acción, que son pasados como parámetros
 function call($controller, $action){
  //importa el controlador desde la carpeta Controllers
  require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');

  //crea el controlador
  switch($controller){
   case 'cliente':
    require_once('Models/claseCliente.php');
    $controller= new ClienteController();
                        switch($action){
        
                                        case 'index':
                                        $controller->index();
                                        break;
                                        case 'registrar':
                                        $controller->register();
        
        
                                    }
                                       break;
            case 'ticket':
                require_once('Models/claseTicket.php');
                $controllerTicket=new TicketController();
                    switch($action){
                        
                            case 'index':
                                $controllerTicket->index();
                                break;
                            case 'buscar':
                                $controllerTicket->buscar();
                    }
    break;
            case 'articulo':
            require_once('Models/claseProducto.php');
                $controllerArt= new ArticuloController();
                switch($action){
                        
                            case 'index':
                                $controllerArt->index();
                                break;
                            case 'buscar':
                                $controllerArt->buscar();
                    }
   }
           
 
 
    }
?>
```